# Как задержать сообщения клиента на сервере python socket?

Tags: python, сокет

Всем привет! Пишу мини чат на socket и tkinter python почти все готово но есть проблема. Когда 1 клиент пытается написать клиенту которого нет в сети то программа закрывается из-за ошибка. Я долго пытался как-то это устранить, и мне сказали задерживать сообщения на сервере пока клиента нету в сети. Но как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: как только поймете, что клиент в сети, отправьте сообщение.

Comment: я так и хочу сделать, просто не знаю как хранить сообщения пока пользователя нету в сети.

Comment: в переменной, список, словарь, файл, база данных и д.т.

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе не нужно, чтобы эти сообщение хранились и после перезагрузки клиентов, то необходимо создать проверку при отправке сообщения. После того, как ты уверен, что тебя на обратном конце слушают, то начать выгрузку сообщений, если соединение не установилось, то отложить сообщения в бд и отдать тогда, когда заново получится соединится с клиентом. Как только пользователь получил твои сообщения он должен отправить тебе обратный ответ, что он получил сообщения и после этого ты можешь удалить сообщения с бд.